# Unable to start Julia connection on port 1023: all connections are in use

Tags: r, julia

I am trying to run Julia function via `R` using `XRJulia` package. Below is my code snippet.

```
## start
library(XRJulia)
prevInterface <- XR::getInterface()
if (is.null(prevInterface)) {
 ev <- RJulia(.makeNew = TRUE)
} else {
 ev <- RJulia(.makeNew = FALSE)
}
juliaAddToPath(directory = '/home/.julia/lib/v0.6/', package = NULL, evaluator = ev)
runjl <- juliaEval('function sum(a, b)
                  c= a+b;
                  return c
                end
               ')
runjl_function <- JuliaFunction(runjl)
sum_result <- runjl_function(1, 5)
XR::rmInterface(XR::getInterface())
## end
```

This code is working fine. But few times when I am running above code multiple times I am getting

> error: Unable to start Julia connection on port 1023: all connections
>   are in use.

How to close all connections of Julia and what is the systematic way..? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have the function ServerQuit() in the RJuliaConnect:

https://github.com/johnmchambers/XRJulia/blob/master/R/RJuliaConnect.R